# Linechart in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, linechart

Code for *java script* function to plot the Line chart is as below:

```
function drawlineChart(plotArea,reqResult,graphFormatingData){

var legendAry = [];
$.each(reqResult.legend , function( index, value ) {
    var obj = {};
    obj['label']=value;
    legendAry.push( obj );
});
var showLegend=true;

var xAxix,yAxix;
xAxix= {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
};
if(graphFormatingData.xAxisType!="undefined" ){

    var min=new Date(reqResult.donutChartData[0][0][0]).getTime();
    var minDate=reqResult.donutChartData[0][0][0];
    var max=new Date(reqResult.donutChartData[0][0][0]).getTime();
    var maxDate=reqResult.donutChartData[0][0][0];

    for(var i=0;i<reqResult.donutChartData.length;i++){
        var doNutChartData=reqResult.donutChartData[i];
        for(var j=0;j<doNutChartData.length;j++){

            var dateCurr=new Date(doNutChartData[j][0]).getTime();
            if(dateCurr<min){
                min=dateCurr;
                minDate=doNutChartData[j][0];
            }
            if(dateCurr>max){
                max=dateCurr;
                maxDate=doNutChartData[j][0];
            }
        }
    }
    if(graphFormatingData.xAxisFormat!=null){
        xAxix= {
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions:{formatString:graphFormatingData.xAxisFormat},
                min:minDate,
                max:maxDate,
                tickInterval:'1 month'
        };
    }
}
 }else{
}
yAxix= {min:0 };
if(graphFormatingData.yAxisType!="undefined"){
    if(graphFormatingData.yAxisFormat!=null){
        yAxix= {
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions:{formatString:graphFormatingData.yAxisFormat},
                tickInterval:'1 month'
        };
    }
}
else if(graphFormatingData.yAxisType!="undefined" ){ 
    yAxix= {
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer, 
            min: 0 ,
            tickOptions: {formatString: "$%'.2f"}
    };
}else{
}

var plot3 = $.jqplot(plotArea, reqResult.donutChartData, 
        { 
    seriesColors:['#6495ED', '#DB7093', '#9A2EFE','#FF0000', '#0040FF', '#04B486','#0B614B','#FA8258','#0B610B','#0B2161','#FFE4E1','#FE2E9A','#8A2908','#5E610B'],
    highlighter: {
    show: true,
    tooltipAxes: 'xy', 
    tooltipLocation:'n',
    useAxesFormatters:true
},
axesDefaults: {
    showTickMarks:true   
},
axes: {
    xaxis: xAxix,
    yaxis: yAxix
} ,
series:legendAry,   
legend: {
    show: true,                      
    location: 'ne',                                 
    showSwatch:true,
    placement: 'outsideGrid'
}
        }  );
```

}

and value of

```
reqResult.donutChartData[0][0][0] is 2016-02.
```

The above function works fine in Chrome, IE11 and Firefox and displays a Line Chart.
But is not Working in Safari. getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.proxy.getTime()')
```

How to fix this Issue in Safari Browser?